# How do I generate an MD5 hash of a string in Visual Studio?

Tags: string, visual-studio, md5

Is there a utility in VS to generate an MD5 hash of a string?

Comment: Are you looking for a function you can call in your program to do this? Or just a utility function for a one-off hash?

Comment: @GregHewgill: just a one-off.

Answer (score 0):

Download the command line utility from here: http://www.fourmilab.ch/md5/

And then:

- Tools/Settings/Expert Settings
- Tools/External Tools

  - Title: md5
  - Command: path/to/md5.exe
  - Args: -d"hello"
  - Tick "Use Output window and Prompt for arguments

Not the best, but works for small strings.

Answer (score 0):

Newer Visual Studios have scripting built in: *View -> Other Windows -> F# Interactive*
So just convert [this](http://www.principiaprogramatica.com/2006/10/02/md5-in-one-line-of-c-code/) oneliner to F# and use it:

```
string hash = Convert.ToBase64String(new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider().
   ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(SomeString)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember you can execute static code from the *Immediate View* without Debug being active (i.e. the application is not running), so if you create a static utility method in your project you could just do:

`My.Project.UtilsClass.MD5Sum("string");`

If you have the string in memory (variable is in scope), you could also do the same thing while debugging:

`My.Project.UtilsClass.MD5Sum(myLocalVar.stringMember);`